# Add Custom Price with product to cart Shopify

Tags: php, shopify

I want to update custom price as hidden option from product details page on click "Add to Cart"....

Like product price is $10

Custom price $5

Total= $15 (I want this needs to added to cart)

Custom price will be changed everytime on selection of custom options in product details page..

So any one can help me out for this how could I do this in shopify????

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make variants to cover the different options. give each one its own price.

Comment: No I cant varintions because variation has fixed price....my price will count on addition on text in textbox or we can say that number of character.....like vijay...... (5 character) mesans price will be 5*2= 10
So on click to add to cart it should add 10 to cart.

Comment: Have you managed to do so ? I am having the same situation and I am managing this by creating another product and adding this to cart for custom buying options.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some JavaScript

```
//update price when changing quantity
  function updatePricing() {
    jQuery('#quantity').val(jQuery('#choose-select-value option:selected').val());

      var quantity  = jQuery('#choose-select-value').val();
      var unitPriceTotal = jQuery('.product .total-price').text(); 


      var totalPrice = unitPriceTotal  * quantity;

      jQuery('.product .price').html().replace(regInput ,totalPrice);
}
```